# Jupyter notebook modulenotfounderror for matplotlib only, other packages ok

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Running on ubuntu 21.20, using a miniconda env, seems to have everything loaded but will not load matplotlib.  So if I try to install it into the conda env  from within the notebook:

```
!conda install -y matplotlib
```

I get this:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

and !conda list clearly shows matplotlib is there, however

```
import matplotlib
```

results in:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33564/2971697587.py in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Any thoughts on how to debug/fix this? Thx. J.

Comment: Try to use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @GreyMurav, Did that, get same error.  Would something called "matplotlib-inline" be causing a problem? Thx. J

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` is a magic function that renders the figure in a notebook (instead of displaying a dump of the figure object). So it is not related with import of matplotlib.

Comment: Do you have more then one python installed on your machine? That can be an issue.

Comment: I do and several conda envs to supposedly control this.  Shouldn't the conda env called into the kernel of the jupyter notebook fix this problem?

Comment: @Jim Maas Use magics or without exclamation point and let automagics handle it. So `!conda install -y matplotlib` should be `%conda install -y matplotlib` inside a cell in the notebook. This new magics insures that the package gets installed into the environment backing the kernel your notebook is using. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magics for `pip` and `conda`. While that won't necessarily sort this out for sure, it's a better practice going forward.

Comment: Sometimes uninstalling and reinstalling using `%conda` or trying installing with `%pip` in a cell in the notebook can get around issues like this if you aren't looking to 100% chase this down since your other packages work.

Comment: @Wayne.  It did, .... have many many many years experience programming and can not figure out python/jupyter.  Was using ! because hundreds of helpful web pages use it, but this area moves so fast that very little info on current syntax!  I may post a solution, trivial but different. Thanks a bunch, spent days on this ... how dumb am I?

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't feel dumb at all. Managing environments is tough. The new magics wouldn't be necessary if it wasn't. Jupyter does keep improving, and so it helps to check around these days. That's part of the purpose of the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/), which is where you may have noted that link I posted can be found. Yes, go ahead and post a solution; it may do what the new magics is doing behind-the-scenes. And sometimes even the magics aren't enough and what you found may help someone else.

Comment: what happens if you do `!pip install matplotlib` ?